# The meaning of "by about a street and three-quarters"

Tags: meaning

> The All Horse Sweep was run, and won by Thurinda **by about a street and three-quarters,** to be very accurate, amid derisive cheers, which Hordene, who flattered himself that he knew something about riding, could not uderstand. On pulling up he looked over his shoulder and saw that the second horse was only just passing the box. “Now, how did I make such a fool of myself?” he said as he returned to weigh out. His friends gathered round him and asked tenderly whether this was the first time that he had got up, and whether it was absolutely necessary that the winning horse should be ridden out when the field were hopelessly pumped, a quarter of a mile behind, etc., etc.

This is from [*"Sleipner", late "Thurinda"* by Rudyard Kipling](https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/sleipner-late-thurinda.htm).

I can't understand the meaning of "by about a street and three-quarters"

Answer (score 11):

"a street" can mean "a longish distance", in idioms like

> We're streets ahead of our rivals = we are a long way ahead...

> The horse won by a street = The horse was a long way in front.

> He missed the goal by a street.

It is a very imprecise distance, so it is a joke to use it as if it were an exact measure. "a street and three-quarters" is a joke made by Kipling to mean that that Thurinda won the race by a very large distance.  This is why there were "derisive cheers".  It was not an exciting race if one horse was so far ahead of the others.

Comment: Thank you so much for your precise answer! I have clearly understood the meaning.

Comment: Sounds like the opposite of a "nose".

Comment: And here I thought the phrase was just a joke that [*Community* made up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCktKQKXNWg).

Comment: I always thought 'streets' in this context was a synonym for 'city blocks' -- the way you might say "go two streets and turn left".